# Can $f(x) + f'(x) + f''(x)$ be negative

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials

Here $f(x)$ is $ax^2 + bx +c$ and, $f(x) > 0$, $a ≠ 0$. The question that I am trying to solve is I have to see whether $g(x) = f(x) + f'(x) + f''(x)$ is :-

i) $g(x) > 0 ~~\forall x\in\Bbb R$

ii) $g(x) < 0 ~~\forall x\in\Bbb R$

iii) $g(x) = 0 ~~\forall x\in\Bbb R$

iv) $g$ has real roots

My initial attempt was checking for all values of $x ≥$ $\frac{-b}{2a}$. In this range of values it can be easily seen that $g(x)$ is going to be positive and cannot be equal to 0.

After this, I went over to the possibility that $x < $$\frac{-b}{2a}$. Once again, it is trivial enough to see that only $f'(x)$ is going to be negative. However, I am unable to check whether the sum $f(x) + f'(x) + f''(x)$ is going to be negative or not.

My second thought process was to observe $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$. By putting $x = \frac{-b-2a}{2a}$, I got the minimum value as $-$ $(\frac{b^2}{4a} + a +c)$.

If $2a$ $≥$ $(\frac{b^2}{4a} + a +c)$, then $g(x)$ $≥$ $0$.

If $2a$ $<$ $(\frac{b^2}{4a} + a +c)$, then $g(x)$ can be negative and positive (implying that it is $0$ for some $x$).

After this, I have no idea how to proceed. I do not know whether this approach will work or not. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $iii$ should be impossible, since $f^\prime, f^{\prime \prime}$ do not contain quadratic terms.

Comment: You know that $b^2-4ac < 0$ since $a$ is not $0$ then neither is $c$ since $b^2 \ge 0$

Comment: Quick tip: for set inclusion, use `\in`, not `\epsilon`. And for the real numbers, use `\mathbb{R}`.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to examine the following:

$$
f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x)=(ax^2+bx+c) + (2ax+b)+2a = \\
=ax^2+(2a+b)x + 2a + b + c
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Recall that the discriminant of a quadratic polynomial $f(x) := a x^2 + b x + c$ is $$\Delta(f) := b^2 - 4 a c ,$$
and that a real quadratic polynomial has no real roots iff its discriminant is negative.

On the other hand, $$g(x) := f(x) + f'(x) + f''(x) = a x^2 + (2 a + b) x + (2 a + b + c).$$ What is the discriminant $\Delta(g)$ of $g$ in terms of $a, b, c$, and how can that quantity be related to $\Delta(f)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=f(x) $. Then,

$$ y+y'+y^{''}=(ax^2+bx+c) + (2ax+b)+2a $$

$$ =ax^2+(2a+b)x + 2a + b + c = a( x-\alpha )(x-\beta) $$

The roots of quadratic equation are

$$(\alpha , \beta)=-(1+b/(2a))\pm \sqrt{\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}-1}   $$

If the quantity under radical sign is not negative ( to exclude complex roots) then the parabola intersects x-axis at two points (roots),  and,

for $$ a>0, \alpha<x < \beta, \;f(x)<0 $$

and for $$ a<0, \alpha<x < \beta, \;f(x)>0. $$